# How to import a single table in Windows environment

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, import, export

I am running Windows 7 with xampp. I can easily import a database with the following command:

```
mysql -u user -p database < backup.sql
```

The problem is that I have a database around 8.5 GB, which take a long long time to import. Mostly I just need to restore a single table from it.

How can i restore single table in this environment?

Comment: If the dump contains the `create table` statements, you can use some text file tools to split the file on those, locate the right one and use only that (or use any text editor able to handle big files to do the same) - or just grep tablename (with sufficient -B and -A) and you should get most of the relevant data.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been dealt with [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387619/how-to-import-a-single-table-in-to-mysql-database-using-command-line). The approach described therein assumes that you have already separated your schema dump by filename.

However, if I've understood you correctly, you have a schema dump from which you wish to extract a single file? I have written a small tool which extracts individual table data separately from a schema dump file.

It's called [MySQLDumpSplitter](https://github.com/Verace/MySQLDumpSplitter). If it doesn't suit your needs, there are two others with the same name also on Github. A Google of "mysqldump file split" or similar will lead you to other tools.

Once you have your Table_name.sql file, just follow the steps outlined in the first link.

DISCLAIMER: I wrote the linked tool. Its limitations are described on the page - you may find others which work better for you.